# Android: showing image in build-in gallery

Tags: android, image, gallery

I'm trying to open a picture in the build-in gallery, but it dosen't show up. I logged the URI to be

06-08 15:53:02.232: D/URI(3231): file:///mnt/sdcard/com.jesper.indkoeb/nm-image.jpg

which is the right place

```
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();  
                    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
                    File file = new File(uri.get(position));
                    Log.d("URI",uri.get(position));
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/*");  
                    context.startActivity(intent);

                }

            });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following Snippet will help you.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/image/Apples.jpg"),"image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @VipulShah i tried you answer code, but it takes about 7-8 sec to show in gallary, i am using android 2.3

Comment: If setData() and setType() are called separately an "No Activity Found" exception is thrown (like it can't find any supported app).